# C# viewmodel to TypeScript

Tags: c#, typescript, mvvm

I have a C# viewmodel:

```
public class LoginModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is not specified")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "No password is specified")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Can I somehow create a typescript viewmodel which will specify the same attributes for Email and Password? I am new to JS (and typescript) and this part is confusing.

Comment: I have already used TypeLite for that, but your question is not clear to me, how would you expect to be renderized your viewmodel after the build?

Comment: Basically what I want, is Password to be shown as dots when typing it in. Currently this is achieved by using "DataType.Password", but if I switch to TypeScript, this won't be happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use t4 template.

https://github.com/cskeppstedt/t4ts

or vs extensions

https://frhagn.github.io/Typewriter/

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NhaBuiDuc.TypescriptSyntaxPaste